# google signin idtoken - user info access delegation

Tags: token, openid-connect, google-signin

I would like to implement a delegation of the user information with Google sign-in in my backend, in principle it should work as follows:

- The user registers with a mobile app.
- The token id gets validated in the Backend.
- The sub field of the token gets stored.
- For every request the idToken is being sent and validated.
- An admin user, after an explicit authorization by the user to access its data, can get an idtoken on behalf of the user.
- the user idtoken is sent to the backend in order to fetch the user data.

Is it possible to delegate the idtoken usage on behalf of a user?

Comment: No, there is no way to get an ID token on behalf of another user without access to their account. But you could implement application logic in your own system whereby you give an admin user access to other user's data?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have some GDPR constrains to cope with. I will insert some logic in order to pseudonimize the user.